# Validating a host using SSL Wildcard certificates

Tags: c++, https, ssl-certificate, poco-libraries

My HTTPS Client uses Poco C++ to connect with our server, which uses a wildcard certificate (`*.example.com`).  The connection fails with a `CertificateValidationException` and the error message is *"Unacceptable certificate from x.y.z.w: application verification failure"*.

The weird thing is it doesn't ALWAYS fail, just most of the time.  After much debugging, my hunch is it has something to do with topology (going across subnets, for example) or with how/when the host name is translated to an I.P. address.

I think this because in cases where everything works as expected, the local DNS is routing the host name.  But in cases where it doesn't work (above error message), the host name translation is on a local box like my PC.

Is there a way to narrow down what's going on here?  Is this a common or known problem?

Thanks.

Comment: One thing I can tell you with 100% certainty is that this has nothing to do with network topology. Guaranteed. There are only two possibilities: 1) Your host is multihomed, and due to misconfiguration it servers the wrong certificate on one of its IP addresses, that you happen to connect to, occasionally, 2) You have a DNS resolution failure, and one of the DNS servers for your zone is returning an IP address for a different host, so depending on which DNS server's cached response was returned to your query, you end up connecting to the wrong host. These are the only possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same symptom myself. Using Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession, I could connect just fine to non-wildcard sites, but failed with the exception and message mentioned above when connecting to *.example.com wildcard sites. Note however that the behavior I observed was 100% consistent, never intermittent.

After debugging through Poco source code, I found the problem in how the HTTPSClientConnection class sets itself up to perform certificate validation. I filed [Poco issue #1303](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/1303)  on pocoproject.org, but the skinny is that if you create an HTTPSClientSession using the no-arg constructor, *you will always get this exception when connecting to server with a wildcard cert.* For example:

```
Poco::URI uri("http://blah.example.com");   // SSL cert is for *.example.com
Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession session;      // Note no-arg constructor
session.setHost(uri.getHost());
session.setPort(uri.getPort());

Poco::Net::HTTPRequest req;
// Populate req...

session.sendRequest(req);      // Throws CertificateValidationException:
                               // "Unacceptable certificate from x.x.x.x,
                               // application verification failure"
```

The problem is that when validating the cert, the various Poco::Net classes look up the peer name as an IP address if the hostname hasn't been set already, and then subsequently try to match that IP addr against the wildcard cert CN (obviously, x.y.z.w will fail to match against *.example.com).

The good news is that there are several easy workarounds. The easiest is to just use the HTTPSClientSession(host, port) constructor, which will set the proper host name on the underlying SecureStreamSocket so that subsequent certificate validation matches a real hostname (blah.example.com) against the cert (CN=*.example.com), instead of an IP addr:

```
Poco::URI uri("http://blah.example.com");
Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());      // Calls SecureStreamSocket::setPeerHostName() internally
```

There are other workarounds, too: create your own SecureStreamSocket first, call setPeerHostName() on it, and then pass that into the appropriate HTTPSClientSession constructor, etc. See the issue tracker link above for a few more ideas if needed.

Comment: FWIW... In my case I'm just opening a socket to the host URL and calling "havePeerCertificate()" on that socket.  It's that call which causes the exception.  I'm using the full host name when I create the URI.

Comment: It is also important to nore that `setPeerHostName()` has to be called before connecting the socket; including through a constructor that connects implicitly. It's best to use `SecureStreamSocket::SecureStreamSocket()` or `SecureStreamSocket::SecureStreamSocket(Context::Ptr pContext, Session::Ptr pSession)` and then call `connect()` afterwards. The [documentation](https://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Net.SecureStreamSocket.html) states which ctors connect implicitly.